# Allow User Input in Empty Cells, Prevent Editing or Deletion in Occupied Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently utilizing Excel VBA to enable the following in my entire sheet:

1. If cell is empty, allow data input.
2. If cell not empty, do not allow data input

The code that I have provided below is able to perform the second requirement by resetting the content back to the original content whenever the user wishes to make changes to an occupied cell. However, when I try to input data for an empty cell, it simply clears the cell, treating it as if the cell is occupied. I am not sure what is wrong with my code here. Hope to seek any advice. Thank you

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Target.Count = 1 Then
            If Target.Value = "" Then
                ' Cell is empty, allow data input
            Else
                ' Cell is not empty, prevent any changes (deletion/input)
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Application.Undo
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is correct because when the event is invoked the cell already contains data (not empty). To get the desired result add the SelectionChange event to your code, and modify the Change event like this

```
Dim buffer As Variant
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Count = 1 Then
buffer = Target
End If
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Target.Count = 1 Then
            If buffer = "" Then
                ' Cell is empty, allow data input
            Else
                ' Cell is not empty, prevent any changes (deletion/input)
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Application.Undo
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please test this scenario:  B3 is non-blank (eg. ABC in the cell), B4 is blank, user modifies B3, the code successfully undo the change (B3 = ABC), try to modify B3 again, the code doesn't work, your input will in cell B3.

Answer (score 1):

The code is a demostration which only support for `single cell` editing.

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim vCell
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
        If vCell <> "" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Undo
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            With Target
                Select Case Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection
                Case Is = xlDown
                    If .Row < Me.Rows.Count Then .Offset(1, 0).Select
                Case Is = xlUp
                    If .Row > 1 Then .Offset(-1, 0).Select
                Case Is = xlLeft
                    If .Column > 1 Then .Offset(-1, 0).Select
                Case Is = xlRight
                    If .Column < Me.Columns.Count Then .Offset(0, 1).Select
                End Select
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then vCell = Target
End Sub
```

---

The more reliable approach is protect the sheet.

- Add a new sheet
- Select all cells, Format Cells > Protection > Uncheck Locked
- Excel Ribbon: Review > Protect Sheet w/o password
- Insert code into sheet module

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    Me.Unprotect
    For Each c In Target.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then c.Locked = True
    Next
    Me.Protect
End Sub
```

All non-blank cells are protected after input. It's no way to change it before unprotecting the sheet.

Comment: The extra code in `Worksheet_Change` is necessary to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you received two answers and accepted one of them, please also try the next approach. It is a little unusual, using `OnUndo` method. Usually, when a VBA code runs all UnDo list is erased. Now, you can even undo the change made in the `Change` event. But its meaning here is to avoid some errors when use `Application.Undo` more times.

So, copy the next code in the sheet to be processed code module. It will raise a (caught) error **at its first run**:

```
Option Explicit

Private TgAddress As String, tgVal

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        Dim actVal: actVal = Target.value
        TgAddress = Target.address: tgVal = actVal
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Undo
            If Target.value = "" Then Target.value = actVal: tgVal = ""
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.OnUndo "Change It Back", "'" & ThisWorkbook.name & "'!" & Me.CodeName & ".ChangeVal"
        Exit Sub
        
ErrorHandler:
        MsgBox "An error occurs..." & vbCrLf & _
               Err.Description, vbInformation, "Error..."
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub ChangeVal() 'Sub to be called when press "Change It Back" from UnDo list
  Application.EnableEvents = False
   Me.Range(TgAddress).value = tgVal
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```